# mysqlplus is better adapter than ruby mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, adapter

I want to know if the [mysqlplus](http://github.com/oldmoe/mysqlplus/) gem is a better database driver than the common [Ruby mysql](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/) gem? I used to have some problems in my Rails application, like:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: MySQL server has gone away

Comment: This really seems to be 2 questions: Is the mysqlplus gem better than standard? and why was I getting x errors?

Comment: maybe the errors is because the standard gem is not so good with concurrent queries, but the error is just a detail, I really wanna know what adapter is better (by your experience) =]

Comment: Also, if this error happens from the Rails `console`, usually `reload!` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL server has gone away` means either the mysql server has crashed running your query or (more commonly) you sent it a quert that is larger than max_allowed_packet. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: the value of max_allowed_packet in my server is 16MB, and I guess that I didn't have big and complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to only check for 'mysql server has gone away' errors then activerecord is more than sufficient. it is a mature codebase, good enough for most usecases.

checkout http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/4/11/automatic-reconnection-of-mysql-connections-in-active-record for more details.

mysqlplus is better when you need *concurrency*, all the cool boys recommend it :-)
but i am not sure if it is production ready.

Comment: DataObjects (used by DataMapper ORM) is also an option, it has the noteworthy objective of providing a consistent api across databases and ruby implementations.     
it's mysql driver is also async, and is said to be better than mysqlplus. another benefit as i see it is that it is integrated with datamapper and has a good test suite and an active community.

Answer (score 0):

mysql reaps the connections after a period of inactivity. this is defined in 'wait_timeout'.
Can see this in mysql by:
  **mysql> show variables like 'wait_timeout'**

by default it is 8 hours. you are getting this error as you have established a connection and there have been no queries executed over this connection for this period.

Activerecord has ActiveRecord::Base#verify_active_connections! for this usecase.
if you specify reconnect: true in database.yml it will do this automatically.

The above method is executed when we checkout a connection from the connection-pool, it guards against inactivity.

It will not help you if you are running a long-running query and it exceeds the **wait_timeout** period, Then you may have to increase the timeout variable in mysql. You may also try setting the patch in:
http://gist.github.com/238999 This will retry the query on such a error, circumstances may have changed, but the patch is not robust as it does not have a retry count.